# placeholder property of select tag in antd not working

Tags: reactjs, antd

This is the code snippet I'm using. The placeholder is not showing in UI. I am using antd controls.

```
<Select placeholder="Select A User Role" value={'RoleID'}>
  <Option value='2'>Company Admin</Option>
  <Option value='3'>Company User</Option>
</Select>
```

[image]

style.css

```
.ant-select-dropdown {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.ant-select-selection-selected-value {
    width: 100%;
  }
.ant-table-tbody > tr > td, .ant-table-thead > tr > th
{
    padding:4px;    
}

tr:nth-child(even){
    background: white;
} 
tr.active { 
background-color: #b3ffb3;
}
thead[class*="ant-table-thead"] th{
    background-color:#000 !important;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-color: #000;
  }
.table_btn
{
    margin:0 !important;
}
.ant-btn
{
    margin:0;
}
.ant-create-invoice-form {
    padding: 24px;   
    margin:24px;
    background: #f1e6ff;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }  
  .ant-create-invoice-header-form {   
    height: 25px; 

  } 
.totallblStyle{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.lblStyle{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.headerlblStyle{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;    
    padding-bottom: 10px;   
}
.headerlblDescStyle{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 260px;    
}
.userHeader{
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headerStyle{
    color: #000;   
}

.gx-main-content-wrapper {
    padding: 5px 20px ; 
}
.ant-table-tbody > tr:hover > td {
    color: #fff;
}
.cancel-btn {
  color: #f0ad4e ;
  border-color: #d9d9d9 ;
}
.cancel-btn:hover {
   background-color: #f0ad4e;
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #eea236;
}
.save-btn {
   color: #3d8918 ;
   border-color: #d9d9d9 ;
}
.save-btn:hover {
    background-color:#3d8918 ;
    color: #fff ;
    border-color: #d9d9d9
}
.loginAs {
   text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sign-up 
.gx-app-login-container {
  max-width: 1000px !important;
}
.gx-user-popover li:hover,
 .gx-user-popover li:focus {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.avtImgStyle{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
.ant-input-disabled {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    color: inherit;
}
.selected {
    background: #545454 !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}

.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
     color:#fff ;
}
.ant-tabs-bar .ant-tabs-tab {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is the style page I am importing in my page.

The place holder for all `<Input>` tags are  working.

But not working for `<Select>`.

Is any of this CSS is preventing the placeholder of ?
How can I make the placeholder of select visible?

Comment: @DragonBorn SO means Ant Design's [Select](https://ant.design/components/select/) component.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem on https://codesandbox.io/s/new?

Comment: There is no problem when I code it in Sandbox. I have to display the values fetched from back end, in the drop down list. When I use the above code in the project the problem arises.

Comment: Are you using `getFieldDecorator`? And what is `RoleId`?

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the width to see it

```
<Select placeholder="Select A User Role" style={{ width: 200 }}>
  <Option value="2">Company Admin</Option>
  <Option value="3">Company User</Option>
</Select>
```

[image]

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4w8yxqm7w4

Comment: I have edited my code . There's a value property in it.

Comment: I have tried your code in my project .But still it's not working

Comment: I added the picture of the UI after trying your code in the question

Comment: hi @JaneFred it was because you already have a fixed value set on it ("RoleID"), remove that value and you can see the placeholder

Comment: I removed the value . Still the problem exists

Comment: @JaneFred what version of antd do you use?

Comment: @baitun I'm using the version  "antd": "^3.7.3"

Comment: @JaneFred it should work. Check your custom styles, maybe it's overriding antd's style. Or provide full code, so we could find an error.

Comment: I've uploaded the styles

Answer (score 1):

The default class selector for `Select` component is `ant-select` (not `ant-select-dropdown` as in the code you provided). Giving the component a width using the correct class name should work.

Also as mentioned in @baitun's comment, you need to remove the `value` property in order to show the placeholder.

Comment: I removed the value property. Still not showing place holder.

Comment: What about the class name I mentioned? The latest version does not use `ant-select-dropdown` in the component. Not sure about the version you're on though.

Comment: Changed class name also . antd version "antd": "^3.7.3",

Comment: Like @baitun has already said, could be other custom styles that are overriding it. Or it could even be an unexpected typo somewhere in your code. Without more code or a reproduced sandbox version, I'm afraid it's very hard for us to debug it any further.

Comment: Thanks! this solved my problem, my `value` was null, now change to `undefined` and working!

Answer (score -1):

I don't if I am right but I think you must code it like below

```
<select>
    <!-- Use an option being selected and disabled default -->
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="">A</option>
    <option value="">B</option>
    <option value="">C</option>
</select>
```

The above code can be used in react and the rest matters regarding binding the data and adding event callbacks.